# Sum of new values

Tags: summation

So I have the following formula

I have found out that

`c={0.308573, 0.404507, 0.356427, 0.652755, 0.402941}`

I was just wondering if there is a easier way of computing this instead of having the following: Because when the time period gets bigger its going to take a while to write.

```
\[Beta]^0*Log[c[[1]]] + \[Beta]^1*Log[c[[2]]] + \[Beta]^2*
  Log[c[[3]]] + \[Beta]^3*Log[c[[4]]] + \[Beta]^4*Log[c[[5]]]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use scalar product of lists here

```
Beta^(Range[5] - 1) .Log[c]
```

Because Attributes are Listable

```
Attributes[{Log, Power}] // TableForm
```

Comment: +1 I think `Beta^Range[0, 4] . Log[c]` is slightly more efficient (measured by `RepeatedTiming`).

Comment: More generally, `Beta^(Range[0,Length[c] - 1]) . Log[c]`

Answer (score 5):

While the answer of @Akku14 is certainly fine, especially as modified by @"Daniel Lichblau", the following might be more communicative in your context:

```
u[c_, t_] := \[Beta]^(t - 1) Log[c]
Sum[u[c[[t]], t], {t, Length[c]}]
```

Answer (score 4):

It should perhaps be noted that the OP is evaluating a polynomial in `β`, and thus, one should use Horner's method for evaluating it; the built-in function that can do this happens to be named `FromDigits[]`:

```
c = {0.308573, 0.404507, 0.356427, 0.652755, 0.402941};
FromDigits[Reverse[Log[c]], β] // Expand
   -1.1758 - 0.905086 β - 1.03163 β^2 - 0.426553 β^3 - 0.908965 β^4
```

Comment: Or if the polynomial is already put together by, say, @DanielLichtblau 's approach:  `Beta^(Range[0, Length[c] - 1]) . Log[c] // HornerForm`.  Does `FromDigits` actually give Horner's method?  It looks like it only partially does so as `FromDigits[Reverse[Log[c]], β]` results in `-1.1758 - 0.905086 Beta + (-1.03163 - 0.426553 Beta) Beta^2 - 
 0.908965 Beta^4` rather than `-1.1758 + 
 Beta (-0.905086 + Beta (-1.03163 + (-0.426553 - 0.908965 Beta) Beta))`.

Comment: @Jim, it's supposed to do Horner (at least in the numerical case), but it looks like it's trying to be clever with symbolic arguments.

Comment: Yep.  What one sees and what's behind the curtain can be totally different.  *Mathematica* is no different.

Answer (score 1):

`MapIndexed` is another possibility (but not as efficient as the dot product method)

```
MapIndexed[(Beta^(First@#2-1)) Log[#1]&, c]//Total
```

In Operator form:

```
MapIndexed[(Beta^(First@#2-1)) Log[#1]&]@c//Total
```

Comment: This is also `Inner` ('a generalization of Dot'): `Inner[(Beta^#2) Log[#1]&, c, Range[0,Length@c-1], Plus]`